# How to set custom path for databricks mlflow artifacts on s3

Tags: databricks, mlflow, aws-databricks, mlops

I've created an empty experiments from databricks experiments console and given the path for my artifacts on s3 i.e. s3:///. When i run the scripts, the artifacts are stored at

```
s3://<bucket>//<32 char id>/artifacts/model-Elasticnet/model.pkl
```

I want to replace //<32 char id>/artifacts/ with /datetime/artifacts/ so something like

```
s3://<bucket>/<datetime>/artifacts/model-Elasticnet/model.pkl
```

Is there any way i could achieve that?

[image]

Note: experiment_id is from databricks experiment console

Comment: Hi, I am in similar case right now.. Have you managed to resolved it? if so, can you let me know how you stored artifacts to S3 bucket, and able to view that from the MLflow Experiments?